# Do unconnected nodes increase render times?

Tags: rendering, node-editor

The question title pretty much says it, does Cycles and Eevee take the time to process nodes that are not connected to the material output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope 
They Don't Increase any render time as the lights in the scene are not scattered according to the unconnected nodes so it will not have any effect on render time but can make your blend file slightly heavier by size

Comment: thanks, that was what I needed to know. :)